# Define array in Swagger OpenAPI annotation

Tags: openapi, swagger-php

I`m using Swagger Editor with OpenAPI 3.0, and I installed swagger-php library. Now  I have a php function with one of its parameter as array, such as:

```
array[(1,2),(2,3),(6,9)]
```

How do I write up the annotation of this array in order to call this function.

Comment: Are you trying to define an array parameter using Swagger-PHP annotations or do you write the API definition manually in Swagger Editor?

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions. I would suggest to implement it with with arrays of objects as it stands in documentation.

```
arrayOfObjects
    description: 'basic array of objects in OpenAPI'
    type: array
    items:
      type: object
      properties:
        num:
          type: integer
```

More info please find here:

[Data Types - Arrays](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#array)